# how to decode json file in php

Tags: php, json, decode

i am trying do decode this json file

```
{"name":"apple","price":1.2312312331231232e 23,"qty":-1,"num":5,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"VZbGneNygMKYCijr"}\n{"name":"orange","price":12,"qty":-7,"num":2,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"d892zf2ccyNlPAZM"}\n{"name":"apple","price":12,"qty":-5,"num":4,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"dja3UQ7vBUs1xBHw"}\n{"name":"apple","price":12,"qty":-7,"num":1,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"yZc1lMB0SKoSIsxw"}\n{"name":"apple","price":12,"qty":-8,"num":3,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"yyPn4UcDin6uAY52"}\n
```

Comment: you are trying, but what the problem ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Read [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: It's a shame lmgtfy is blocked from the comments ...

Comment: you are not getting right output because of `"price":1.2312312331231232e 23` , your string in not in json format, Check this : https://eval.in/605084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to read a file, let's say file_get_contents()

```
$file = file_get_contents('FILE WITH FULL PATH');

$decoded = json_decode ($file);

var_dump($decoded);
```

You are OK.

Comment: only getting first json object

Comment: multi object in same file like this

Comment: {"name":"orange","price":60,"qty":null,"num":2,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"HmoYUIEtCrrx6R3n"}
{"name":"apple","price":12,"qty":-11,"num":1,"color":"","category":"FRUITS","_id":"yJQXJL9AQBq2YmPS"}